# What is the Intersection between $H^2$ and $H^1_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, finite-element-method

I'm currently following an introductory course on Finite Element Methods, where we make extensive use of some Sobolev spaces to ensure regularity on our approximate solutions.

For a given domain, $\Omega$, we have the following defined (which I believe to be pretty standard):

- $L_2(\Omega) := \{u : \int_\Omega u^2 < \infty\}$
- $H^m(\Omega) := \{u \in L_2(\Omega) : D^\alpha u \in L_2(\Omega), \forall |\alpha| \leq m \}$ ($\alpha$ is the multi-index for taking all combinations of derivatives)
- $H^m_0(\Omega) := \{u \in H^m(\Omega) : u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0\}$

Within the course and in some other courses I've found the notes for online, I've noticed that $H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ has been used... But what's the difference between that and $H^2_0(\Omega)$?

Is there a difference that I'm overlooking, an inconsistency on whoever wrote the notes, or do I have my definitions of the function spaces wrong?

Comment: Your definition of $H_0^m$ is not the usual one. Typically, $H_0^m(\Omega)$ is defined as the completion of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $H^m(\Omega)$. With your definition, $H_0^2 = H^2 \cap H_0^1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by gerw, this answer uses the standard definition of $H^m_0$:
$$
H^m_0 = \text{closure of } C_c^\infty(\Omega) \text{ wrt to $H^m$-norm}
$$
Functions in $H^2\cap H^1_0$ have zero boundary values, while for functions in $H^2_0$ the function itself and its first derivatives are zero on the boundary.

Comment: This is not true for the given definition of $H_0^2$.

Comment: Yes. Missed that!

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old post, but is it safe to say that the norm on $H^2 \cap H^1_0$ is the same $H^2$-norm?

Comment: yes. ...............